# Stuwkach, Poland listed in Obituary

Tags: immigration, poland, historical-gazetteer, genealogical-societies

Trying to find out where Stuwkach, Poland refers to in my great grandmothers obituary. She was born in 1894 and immigrated in 1911 (according to the 1930 US census) was Roman Catholic

[Her obit](http://findagrave.com/memorial/53886547/frances-bartnik) is listed on find a grave. Her parents birth place is listed as Austria, Poland, and Galicia depending on the census year. Haven't found her immigration records yet.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Have you located your great grandmother's immigration records?  Those might also have her place of birth, and in that case it might be provided first-hand and (possibly) be spelled correctly.

Comment: Hi Laura, have you located the record of your great-grandmother's marriage to your ggf, which indicates that this was her second marriage (and gives both her maiden name and her first married name)?

Comment: Here is the newspaper with the 1982 obit: http://newspapers.rawson.lib.mi.us/chronicle/1982/Issues/04-22-1982.pdf

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I haven't found immigration records. I do have her marriage records which list her maiden name, first married name, and second married name...I've tried them all with variations on spelling and no luck in finding her birth records, or immigration/naturalization records.